# CentOS wrong outgoing IP address on forward

Tags: centos, ip, kvm-virtualization

I have a rather strange behaviour for me in here. I am trying to forward traffic between two interfaces (one being a bridge) but will not work as intended.
Here is the setup:

Kvm host has br0 (192.168.1.25) br1 (10.128.3.1) and bond2 (10.128.5.1)
The guest is attached to br1 and has gateway set for 10.128.3.1
The kvm host has ip forwaring enable and the following routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
10.128.3.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.128.3.1
10.128.5.0/24 via 10.128.5.1 dev bond2
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.25
```

the kvm guest can ping 10.128.5.1 which resides on the kvm host. Also, I tried to add a route in the guest for the 10.128.5.0/24 via 10.128.5.1 which guest can access

what is happening on the other end I am pinging is the following:

```
11:54:14.708483 IP 192.168.1.25 > 10.128.5.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 606, length 40
```

So, it originates that ping with the wrong interface and ip
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the complete output of "ifconfig", "route -n" and "brctl show" ?

Comment: Also it's not clear who do you ping and from where?